# Why does Haskell's find always return only one element?

Tags: haskell

```
Prelude> find odd [2,4,7,9,11]
Just 7
```

I would expect this to return [7,9,11], as they're all odd numbers. Why does `find` return `Just 7`?

Is there any way I can tell the `odd` function to return what I expect?

Comment: In such cases you should figure out the function type for your need then  ask [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle).  For this task search param is **(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:find):

> The `find` function takes a predicate and a list and returns the **first** element in the list matching the predicate, or `Nothing` if there is no such element.

Use [`filter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:filter) instead:

```
> filter odd [2,4,7,9,11]
[7, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `filter`

```
> filter odd [2,4,7,9,11]
[7, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `filter`, not `find`. The job of `find` is to find the first one, or let you know there isn't one. The job of `filter` is to make a list of all of them.